# How to pass a date in query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table which has a begin date and an end date. I have to fetch these dates and check whether these dates are in the range of a column value of another table...

I have tried by fetching begindate, and enddate using a `select` query and have used  the `between` keyword to check the range

```
select invoice 
from customer 
where BOOK_DATE BETWEEN(select begindate, enddate 
                        from Period 
                        where i_status = 1)
```

Actual result : missing key word
Expected result : Ex: Begin Date = 1-May-19, End Date = 31-May-19 and book_date = 15-May-19, it should return invoice num something like '123ABC'

Comment: can you join the tables somehow? What is the common link?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that checks if a row in period exists, where the booking date is between the begin and end date and the status is 1.

```
SELECT c.invoice
       FROM customer c
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM period p
                            WHERE c.book_date BETWEEN p.begindate
                                                      AND p.enddate
                                  AND p.i_status = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Between has an AND between them, you should try

```
BETWEEN(SELECT begindate FROM Period WHERE i_status = 1) AND (SELECT enddate FROM 
Period WHERE i_status = 1)
```